# Trigger is firing always regardless of conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a trigger to raise an exception when a credit card expiration date is expired. No matter what date I insert, the exception is raised. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger card_expired
before insert or update on invoice
for each row
begin
  if :new.exp_date >= sysdate
  then
    raise_application_error(-20000,'Card is expired');
  end if;
end;
```

Insert Statement(exp_date is 12-31-19):

```
insert into invoice(invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_due, cc_type, cc_no,
exp_date, guest_id, reservation_id, admins_id)
values(invoice_sequence.nextval, sysdate, bill_due(100101), 'Visa', 
'4838892900203328', to_date('12-31-2019','mm/dd/yyyy'), 110, 100101, 110);
```

Comment: You don't have a column list in your insert. So we don't know what you're inserting where and your code is inviting bugs. Always use an insert list. If you add one you might find your unexpected behaviour goes away

Comment: Also your year literal doesn't have a century. Is 19 = 1919 or 2019? If your code doesn't have ambiguities you are much less likely to have bugs or unexpected behaviour, now or in the future.

Comment: 2019-12-31 is certainly greater than SYSDATE, so your trigger is working.

Comment: On a side note: The date string `'12-31-2019'`  doesn't match the pattern `'mm/dd/yyyy'`. (That should rather be `'mm-dd-yyyy'`). And why use a string and a conversion function (`TO_DATE`) at all and not a date literal directly (i.e. `date '2019-31-12'`)?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Oracle doesn't care about punctuation in date formats unless we use the strict notation in our mask. But consistency is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your check is wrong, instead of `>=` it should be `<=`!

```
:new.exp_date >= sysdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: `exp_date` is 6th parameter in the insert statement.

Given format in `to_date` in fact doesn't match the given date.

Please check:

```
select to_char(to_date('12-31-19','mm/dd/yyyy'), 'mm-dd-yyyy') from dual;
```

It gives:

```
12-31-0019
```

Therefore it is always less than SYSDATE.

This should solve your issue:

```
to_date('12-31-19','mm-dd-yy')
```

Or even better (to not be confused about century):

```
to_date('12-31-2019','mm-dd-yyyy')
```

Comment: If you skip century you should use `to_date('12-31-19','mm-dd-rr')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - if we use `yy` Oracle defaults to the current century. In this case that is more likely to be correct than `rr`. But the best solution is to always use explicit four digit years.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. For the ones confused about a difference between formats `yy` and `rr`: [The RR Datetime Format Element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00215). But still, as @APC said. I prefer to always use explicit four digit years.

Comment: @APC, well in case of `yy` kate8895 should tell us for which bank he/she is working. Maybe I will find a 20 years old credit card which then I can use for the rest of my life. :-)